# GROOVY: Finding a string from console output if a regexp string found

Tags: jenkins, logging, groovy, jenkins-plugins, post-build

I have the following console output from a jenkins build:

```
23:21:16  [ ERROR ] - Problem occured while installing the chart AbCdEfG , aborting!
```

if the line appears, i want to be able to get only AbCdEfG and put it in error message, or in a varaiable.
i tried something like:

```
if (manager.logContains('.*\${error_string}')) {
     error("Build failed because of ${AbCdEfG}")
```

regexp string that seems to be working, but stuck

```
[\n\r]*Problem occured while installing the chart:*([^\n\r]*)
```

Comment: def regex = '(?<=Problem occured while installing the chart).*?(?<=\\s).*?(?=\\s)'
                    if (manager.logContains('.*Problem occured while installing the chart.*')) {
                    def msg = manager.getLogMatcher(regex)
                        error  "$msg"

i got to Here, but the regex is returning NULL :\

Comment: Hi, can you edit your own question with the updates? Add EDIT or UPDATE would be enough. Regardless of the note, the example 4 (https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy-postbuild/) won't work for you? getLogMatcher is not returning a msg but a Matcher.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tested example 4 from [plugin documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy-postbuild/)? That example is using Java, not Groovy.

Anyway, the method `getLogMatcher` returns a Matcher, not a String.

Calling `logContains` will [evaluate the log twice](https://github.com/jenkinsci/groovy-postbuild-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jvnet/hudson/plugins/groovypostbuild/GroovyPostbuildRecorder.java).

Using [Groovy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), (not tested inside Jenkins, only locally) you can adapt this snippet:

```
​    def matcher = ("23:21:16  [ ERROR ] - Problem occured while installing the chart AbCdEfG , aborting!" =~ /Problem occured while installing the chart\s?([^\n\r]*)\s?, aborting!/)

    /* One item from array is the group, first item from this group is the full match and the second is group match */
    if (matcher.hasGroup()) {
        def msg = matcher[0][1]
        println("Build failed because of ${msg}")
    }
```

Comment: it is working!
thanks for the deatils answer!!

Comment: @KobeVaknin Great!! When what a person post it works or answer your question. if you are not waiting for other responses, please mark this as an accepted answer, otherwise, comment any doubts. :)