# How to parse output jenkins console, return value and save in variable

Tags: regex, parsing, jenkins

I'm having trouble parsing the jenkins pipeline console output.
Every time I pass a job, a line appears in the console:

```
12:29:08 [10:29:07] NIDD version is: SBTS23R1_NIDD_2217_100_01
```

[image]

I would like to extract a variable value from it: SBTS23R1_NIDD_2217_100_01
and save it in a variable so that I can use it further.

I tried to do something like described here:
[GROOVY: Finding a string from console output if a regexp string found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65314154/groovy-finding-a-string-from-console-output-if-a-regexp-string-found)

Unfortunately, I am getting the error:

```
an exception which occurred:
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@20cd216a
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef.capture
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef@3e3cd6ed
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosure.def
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@6be3d3c7
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@14fde9cd
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@14fde9cd
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.regex.Matcher
```

My code :

```
def matcher = ("12:29:08 [10:29:07] NIDD version is: SBTS23R1_NIDD_2217_100_01" =~ /NIDD version is:\SBTS\d{2}\w\d_NIDD_\d{4}_\d{3}_\d{2}/) 

if (matcher.hasGroup()) 
{ 
  def msg = matcher[0][1] println("Build failed because of ${msg}") 
}
```

Comment: What is the code that results in this error?

Comment: def matcher = ("12:29:08  [10:29:07] NIDD version is: SBTS23R1_NIDD_2217_100_01" =~ /NIDD version is:\SBTS\d{2}\w\d_NIDD_\d{4}_\d{3}_\d{2}/)

if (matcher.hasGroup()) {
        def msg = matcher[0][1]
        println("Build failed because of ${msg}")
    }

Comment: Looks like you missed `\s*` and a group that you refer to later from the code. Try https://ideone.com/5zO4d9

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a capturing group and consume any amount of spaces between a colon and `SBT` (you mistakenly escaped `S` making `S` in `SBT` part of a non-whitespace matching shorthand character class):

```
def matcher = ("12:29:08 [10:29:07] NIDD version is: SBTS23R1_NIDD_2217_100_01" =~ /NIDD version is:\s*(SBTS\d{2}\w\d_NIDD_\d{4}_\d{3}_\d{2})/)
if (matcher) {
    def msg = matcher[0][1]
    println("Build failed because of ${msg}")
}
```

See the [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/5zO4d9).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll check if it works tomorrow and let you know

Comment: Your fixes work, but something is wrong because the code looks for the NIDD value in what was typed in the code
("12:29:08 [10:29:07] NIDD version is: SBTS23R1_NIDD_2217_100_01")
not the entire job console